# ASP.NET REST API Return Array

Tags: c#, .net, rest

I'm new to asp.net and c# in general and am working on building a REST API. I'm mostly there following many tutorials, including http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/create-a-rest-api-with-attribute-routing
which has helped tremendously.

The one area where I'm struggling is returning an array of foreign keyed objects.

I have an object with an id, e.g., an Activity, and various other data. I have another object, e.g., ImageReference, that has an id as well, and also a foreign key of activityID. The activity can have many ImageReference related objects.

For the REST api, with a GET of the activity, I want to return all the related (foreign keyed) ImageReference. I have figured out how to return a single related object:

```
    [Route("~/api/locations/{zip}/activities")]
    public IQueryable<ActivityDto> GetActivitiesByZip(int zip)
    {
        return db.Activities.Include(b => b.Location)
            .Where(b => b.Location.Zip == zip)
            .Select(AsActivityDto);
    }
```

and

```
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(ActivityDto))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetActivity(int id)
    {
        ActivityDto activity = await db.Activities.Include(b => b.Location)
            .Where(b => b.Id == id)
            .Select(AsActivityDto)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        if (activity == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(activity);
    }
```

However, I am unable to figure out how to return multiple related objects. I'm looking for returning something like:

```
 <ActivityDto>
 <Id>3</Id>
 <Name>Activity Name</Name>
 <Zip>80204</Zip>
 <ImageReference>
     <Id>1</Id>
     <ImageURL>
       https://example.net/images/f869ce1c8414a264bb11e14a2c8850ed
     </ImageURL>
     <Id>2</Id>
     <ImageURL>
       https://example.net/images/kC9gANXxMIi8fWj1BbY2ntZ9SaLo3
     </ImageURL>
 </ImageReference>
 </ActivityDto>
```

I sincerely appreciate the help!

Comment: What happens when you call those endpoints? What response do you get? What do you expect to get?

Comment: @scheien Just edited to add more context - thanks!

Comment: What is it returning now?

Comment: @scheien just the activity, 
<ActivityDto>
 <Id>3</Id>
 <Name>Activity Name</Name>
 <Zip>80204</Zip></ActivityDto>

I want it to include the related ImageReferences, and not just the activity

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this, you can chain the includes

```
[Route("{id:int}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(ActivityDto))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetActivity(int id)
{
    ActivityDto activity = await db.Activities.Include(b => b.Location)
        .Include(act => act.ImageReferences)
        .Include(act => act.Location.ObjectInLocation)          
        .Where(b => b.Id == id)
        .Select(AsActivityDto)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    if (activity == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(activity);
}
```

This is with these classes

```
public class Location
{
    public X ObjectInLocation{get;set;}
}

public ImageReference
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string ImageUrl{get;set;}
}

public class Activity
{

    public Location Location{get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<ImageReference> ImageReferences{get;set;}

}
```